# What is the name of this type of stochastic processes?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, terminology

I've seen someone briefly define a continuous time stochastic process $X$ on $\mathbb{N}$ as the (a?) solution to

$$X(t)=X(0)+Y\left(\int_0^t f(X(s))ds\right)$$

where $Y$ is an inhomogeneous Poisson process with cumulative rate $\int_0^t f(X(s))ds$ and $f:\mathbb{N}\to[0,\infty)$. What are processes of this form referred to and where could I find out more about them? Are they sort of state-dependent queue or jump Markov process?